# Open an excel worksheet

Tags: c#, excel

How to open a specific workbook of an excel sheet? Currently I am using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```

but it just opens that excel. I would like to focus in to a specific worksheet.

How to do it? Is it possible using

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Comment: Do you need to launch Excel with specific Workbook open? Or do you need to extract Excel data to use in your program?

Comment: Yea i need to open Excel with specific worksheet open.

Comment: There are several ways of doing it. If you target only Excel >= `2007` I recommend using **[Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425)** and other libs based on it.